# An Important Question about NSString

Tags: cocoa, iphone-sdk-3.0, nsstring, ios4

The problem is after i press 2 buttons the App crashes and I can't figure out why

Button1 is wired to button1
Button2 is wired to button2
...
Button5 is wired to button5

What am I doing wrong?

Basically I want to check if the sequence of #'s is punched in correctly (55235)

In my AppDelegate.H file, I've defined a variable called

NSString* myEasterEgg;

In AppDelegate.M, I have 5 buttons that are correctly wired and each button has it's own method

```
-(IBAction)button1:(id)sender
{
if(CFStringCompare((CFStringRef)myEasterEgg, (CFStringRef)@"52235", 1) == 0)
{
myEasterEgg = @"";
} else {
myEasterEgg = [myEasterEgg stringByAppendingString:@"1"];
}
}

-(IBAction)button2:(id)sender
{
if(CFStringCompare((CFStringRef)myEasterEgg, (CFStringRef)@"52235", 1) == 0)
{
myEasterEgg = @"";
} else {
myEasterEgg = [myEasterEgg stringByAppendingString:@"2"];
}
}

-(IBAction)button3:(id)sender
{
if(CFStringCompare((CFStringRef)myEasterEgg, (CFStringRef)@"52235", 1) == 0)
{
myEasterEgg = @"";
} else {
myEasterEgg = [myEasterEgg stringByAppendingString:@"3"];
}
}

-(IBAction)button4:(id)sender
{
if(CFStringCompare((CFStringRef)myEasterEgg, (CFStringRef)@"52235", 1) == 0)
{
myEasterEgg = @"";
} else {
myEasterEgg = [myEasterEgg stringByAppendingString:@"4"];
}
}

-(IBAction)button5:(id)sender
{
if(CFStringCompare((CFStringRef)myEasterEgg, (CFStringRef)@"52235", 1) == 0)
{
myEasterEgg = @"";
} else {
myEasterEgg = [myEasterEgg stringByAppendingString:@"5"];
}
}

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
myEasterEgg = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@""];
}
```

Comment: I get this error

EXC_BAD_ACCESS and stringByAppendingString

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are leaking your original string, and replacing it with new values without retaining them. The crash happens because you’re calling `[myEasterEgg stringByAppendingString:…]` on a dangling pointer, that is, a variable which no longer refers to any object. See the [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html) for more information.

Comment: I'm at work and when I click that link causes HTML rendering issues. Could you please tell me how I can fix it?

Comment: I'm using IE6 because we're not allowed to install a real browser.